# saving picture on canvas using picturerecorder, but it returns null

Tags: image, canvas, flutter, dart

I'm struggling to learn about flutter, and making an application which is going to be used for getting some signatures.
What I want to make is a page which get a signature from users and save it.
Additionally, I make a floatingactionbutton to clear the canvas, save the picture, and go to next page. But whenever i click the button, always empty images come through the canvas. How could I fix it? I don't know how to put picture recorder to custom painter class.
Here's my code.(cf. my flutter version is the latest version, and have no problem with flutter doctor)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'last_page.dart';

import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:image/image.dart';

import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:async';


class SignPage extends StatefulWidget { 

  @override
  _SignPageState createState() => _SignPageState();
}

class _SignPageState extends State<SignPage> {

  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    print(directory.path);

    return directory.path;
  }



  var now = new DateTime.now();
  ui.PictureRecorder _pictureRecorder = new ui.PictureRecorder();
  ByteData image;

  List<Offset> _points = <Offset>[];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Center(child: new Text("Please Sign In."),),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new GestureDetector(
          onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details){
            setState(() {
              RenderBox object = context.findRenderObject();
              Offset _localPosition = object.globalToLocal((details.globalPosition));
              _points = new List.from(_points)..add(_localPosition);
            });
          },
          onPanEnd: (DragEndDetails details) => _points.add(null),
//          child: new CustomPaint(painter: new Signature(_points, _canvas, widget.pictureRecorder),size: Size.infinite,),
          child: new CustomPaint(painter: new Signature(points:_points),size: Size.infinite,),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: new Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          ui.Picture picture = _pictureRecorder.endRecording();
          image = picture.toImage(300, 300);
          ByteData pngBytes =  await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
          File('~/AndroidStudioProjects/pagetest/images').writeAsBytesSync(pngBytes.buffer.asInt8List());

          _points.clear();
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LastPage())
          );
        },
      ),

    );
  }
}

class Signature extends CustomPainter {

  List<Offset> points;

  Signature({this.points});




  @override
  void paint(ui.Canvas canvas, ui.Size size) {
    Paint paint = new Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 5.0;


    for (int i = 0; i<points.length-1; i++){
      if(points[i] != null && points[i+1] != null){
        canvas.drawLine(points[i], points[i+1], paint);
      }
    }

  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(Signature oldDelegate) => oldDelegate.points != points;



}
```

Comment: where are you creating a canvas like: `Canvas(_pictureRecorder)`? have you read [PictureRecorder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/PictureRecorder-class.html) documentation? they say: *"To begin recording, construct a Canvas to record the commands. To end recording, use the PictureRecorder.endRecording method."*

Comment: Actually, I don't create a new Canvas class. I used it in the Signature class extends CustomPainter class, to override void paint function. Canvas class is just called in the function in void paint(Canvas canvas), so I can't modify it. That's the biggest problem. I don't know how to use the PictureRecorder class in that position.

Comment: so maybe google for `RepaintBoundary` and `RenderRepaintBoundary` classes - `RenderRepaintBoundary` class has `toImage` method which could be interesting to you

Comment: thank you for your answer. it helped me a lot. now i can get captured image from the widget.

Comment: good, so you are using `RepaintBoundary` now?

Comment: yes i'm using it now.